# Default date range for jQuery-UI's datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery-UI to create a date range field. What I am trying to do is have my StartDate default to today's date minus seven days and have my EndDate default to "today's" date. Still allowing the dates to be changed if the user wants to change the dates. As well as not allowing the user to select a date in the future (After today's date). Is this all possible with jQuery-UI's datepicker?

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
      from = $( "#StartDate" )
        .datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 1
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  } );
  </script>

<span class="srch_title" for="StartDate">From</span>
<input type='text' name="StartDate" id="StartDate" value="" required/>

<span class="srch_title" for="EndDate">To</span>
<input type='text' name="EndDate" id="EndDate" value="" required/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/fdLy2n12/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use setDate property and change the default date .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand criteria correctly the following should do what is expected

```
$(function() {
  var today = new Date(),
    weekAgo = new Date(),
    $from = $("#StartDate"),
    $to = $("#EndDate");

  weekAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);

  $from.datepicker({   
    maxDate: today,
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
    }
  }).datepicker('setDate', weekAgo);

  $to.datepicker({
    maxDate: today,
    minDate: weekAgo,
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dateText);
    }
  }).datepicker('setDate', today);

});
```

Not sure if `from` needs a minDate or not

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fdLy2n12/6/)**</kbd>

Comment: How did you get yours to show in your text fields? When I use your code it still does not show :(

Comment: so weird in my app its not filling in the text fields but in the fiddle it is.

Comment: Its not your code its me I have a select that drops the date values down and when the select is chosen it does this `generatereportform[0].reset();`

Comment: So its probably clearing those fields I have to figure out how to show it after it clears them.

Comment: Note I updated removing `changeMonth` and `numberOfMonths` since you are working in sepecifc range

Comment: after the reset initialize the datepickers again with the above defaults

Comment: when I commented out the resets it works right. What do you mean reset the defaults? I moved the code underneath it all thinking it would run last but that did not fix it

Comment: fiddle having problems doing a fork right now. Just wrap all the datepicker code in a function...call that at end ef your `change` handler

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that unfortunately :( It wont allow you to make the change and update it?

Comment: No..have used fiddle for years. Not creating new url's right now for some reason